# How do you add a navigationBar when you're not using a navigationController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Is there a way of doing this other than dragging one onto the view in IB? I see in IB that you can specify that a view has a naviationBar but that only seems to work when I am using a navigationController. The app I'm working on isn't a good fit for navigationController. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UINavigationBar is a view like any other.  Simply set an appropriate frame and add it to the view you wish.

ex:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)];
[self.view addSubview:bar];
[bar release];
```

n.b. I am not sure the of the standard height off hand, but that'll be easy to find

**Edit: Looks like I was beaten to the punch**

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use the `UINavigationBar` class—it's a subclass of `UIView`, so you can just add it to your view hierarchy. You'll have to manually manage its stack of `UINavigationItem`s, but if you do that right then you can get about the same behavior out of it as you would with a `UINavigationController`.